# I want to get version number of Application from playstore in flutter

Tags: flutter, web-scraping, jsoup, html-parsing

In android, we used to get version number from playstore using **JSOUP dependency** but in flutter, not able to find the alternate

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you https://pub.dev/packages/package_info
It can give you the installed version of the application.

Comment: Bro, I want app version number from playstore not from installed application, anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a powerful library for crawling. Please read docs for more informations and example. 
[Docs here](https://pub.dev/packages/scrapy#-readme-tab-)

Comment: can I have code snipped to get version number from [play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp] @user8773560

Answer (score -1):

Try my package : [google_play_scraper](https://pub.dev/packages/google_play_scraper)

```dart
import 'package:google_play_scraper/google_play_scraper.dart';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  var appId = 'com.dts.freefireth';
  GooglePlayScraper scraper = GooglePlayScraper();
  var app = await scraper.app(appId: appId);
  print(app.version); // 1.92.1
}
```

Comment: Sifat, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)